# using $ionic Popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi Im using ionic to create a simple popup. Here Im not able to display the pop-up information after clicking the button. I don't know where Im going wrong and please help me in displaying the pop-up .And Im getting error

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.showPopup
```

[link](http://codepen.io/jazz_oria/pen/rrzOoB)

```
angular.module('CarWash',[$ionic]).controller('popSelect',['$scope',function($scope,$ionicPopup){
$scope.data={};
$scope.showPopup = function() {
       $ionicPopup.show({
            title:'select car wash',
            template: "Hello customer !!!",

        });
        alertpop.then(function(res){
          console.log('Inside pop-up');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed in Dependency injection, you have to inject `$ionicPopup` to use it in controller factory function.

```
angular.module('CarWash',[$ionic])
.controller('popSelect',['$scope', '$ionicPopup', //<-- injected $ionicPopup here
   function($scope, $ionicPopup){ //<-- now you can access $ionicPopup instance here.
```

Comment: @sree glad to help you, Thanks :-)

Comment: I have a doubt in ionic list can you help me with it.

Comment: Could you add new question please?

Comment: this is my question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825976/understanding-the-ionic-select