# understanding the ionic select

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to use ionic list to display a set of cars, when the particular car is selected it should display a small description of it and also editable. Here Im unable to display the description of the item selected. Also please let me know how to edit the description and update it.

[link here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ntXafxbffSbgYAv85RC0?p=preview)

this is the controller

```
car.controller('popSelect', ['$scope','$ionicPopup', function ($scope, $ionicPopup) {
   $scope.homePage = function () {
    window.location = "#/menu.html"
  }

  $scope.carList = [{ value: "Honda", description: "Its honda" },
    { value: "Toyota", description: "Its Toyota" },
    { value: "BMW", description: "Its BMW" }];
  //$scope.carList=['Bmw','Mercedes','Honda'];
  $scope.select_item = function (key) {
    {{item.decription}}
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes in Index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <h4>Select car</h4>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-click="select_item(value)" ng-repeat="(key,value) in carList"> 

      {{value.value}} 

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list><hr>
          <div style="text-align:center">
    <button class="button3" ng-click="showPopup()">ADD</button><hr>
    <button  class="button2" ng-click="homePage()">Back</button>
    <button class=" button2" ng-click="deleteSelected()">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div>{{description}}</div>
     <!--{{couponTitle}} {{couponDescribe}} {{validFrom}} {{validTo}} -->
  </body>
```

In your js

```
var car=angular.module('myApp',[]);
car.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.homePage = function () {
    window.location = "#/menu.html"
  }
 // $scope.description = '';
  $scope.selectedItem = 'select';
  $scope.items=[];
  $scope.carList = [{ value: "Honda", description: "Its honda" },
    { value: "Toyota", description: "Its Toyota" },
    { value: "BMW", description: "Its BMW" }];
  //$scope.carList=['Bmw','Mercedes','Honda'];
  $scope.select_item = function (key) {
    $scope.description=key.description;
  }
}]);
```

Thanks (Y)

Comment: Can I know why $scope.items.push(key) is used?. And if I use that will I be able to edit the description and update the new description.

Comment: Just so you can add multiple description and show them .. and also you can perform certain operation on them sperately :)

Comment: never use  {{item.decription}} these expression in js file , Its for html to be rendered according to your scope variable (Y)

Comment: I want to display only one description with respective to the item clicked in the list.... but here when i click honda it gives correct description but when another item say BMW is clicked it displays the both honda and BMW description. I want to display respective decription when a item from lit is clicked @Ujjwal kaushik